# Adding entries to row in order to make it uniform

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a `csv` file with dates, repair_id, number of onsite repairs and number of offsite repairs, so that my data looks as:

```
data        repair_id    num_onsite     num_offsite
2016-02-01          A             3              0
2016-02-01          B             2              1
2016-02-01          D             0              4
2016-02-02          A             1              3
2016-02-02          C             1              1
2016-02-02          E             0              6
...
2016-02-14          A             1              3
2016-02-14          B             0              4
2016-02-14          D             2              0
2016-02-14          E             3              0
```

There are 5 different `repair_id`, namely: `A, B, C, D, E`. If a repair man (`repair_id`) had no work on a given date then they are not in the csv file for that date. I would like to change that by including them and have a `0` value
for `num_onsite` and `num_offsite` so that my table would resemble:

```
data        repair_id    num_onsite     num_offsite
2016-02-01          A             3              0
2016-02-01          B             2              1
2016-02-01          C             0              0 # added
2016-02-01          D             0              4
2016-02-01          E             0              0 # added
2016-02-02          A             1              3
2016-02-02          B             0              0 # added
2016-02-02          C             1              1
2016-02-02          D             0              0 # added
2016-02-02          E             0              6
...
2016-02-14          A             1              3
2016-02-14          B             0              4
2016-02-14          C             0              0 # added
2016-02-14          D             2              0
2016-02-14          E             3              0
```

I've had a look at:

[Pandas DataFrame insert / fill missing rows from previous dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093971/pandas-dataframe-insert-fill-missing-rows-from-previous-dates)

[Missing data, insert rows in Pandas and fill with NAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909984/missing-data-insert-rows-in-pandas-and-fill-with-nan)

[Add missing dates to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe)

but I wasn't able to get it to output properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.set_index(["data","repair_id"]).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()      



        data repair_id  num_onsite  num_offsite
0 2016-02-01         A         3.0          0.0
1 2016-02-01         B         2.0          1.0
2 2016-02-01         C         0.0          0.0
3 2016-02-01         D         0.0          4.0
4 2016-02-01         E         0.0          0.0
5 2016-02-02         A         1.0          3.0
6 2016-02-02         B         0.0          0.0
7 2016-02-02         C         1.0          1.0
8 2016-02-02         D         0.0          0.0
9 2016-02-02         E         0.0          6.0
```

Comment: Great answer, improve it with `fill_value=0`.  Like this: `df.set_index(["data","repair_id"]).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index() `

Answer (score 3):

Set the index, reindex with `fill_value`, then `reset_index`

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [df.data.unique(), df.repair_id.unique()],
    names=['data', 'repair_id']
)

df.set_index(['data', 'repair_id']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()

          data repair_id  num_onsite  num_offsite
0   2016-02-01         A           3            0
1   2016-02-01         B           2            1
2   2016-02-01         D           0            4
3   2016-02-01         C           0            0
4   2016-02-01         E           0            0
5   2016-02-02         A           1            3
6   2016-02-02         B           0            0
7   2016-02-02         D           0            0
8   2016-02-02         C           1            1
9   2016-02-02         E           0            6
10  2016-02-14         A           1            3
11  2016-02-14         B           0            4
12  2016-02-14         D           2            0
13  2016-02-14         C           0            0
14  2016-02-14         E           3            0
```

Answer (score 2):

And for those of us with the SQL mentality, consider merging (*left join*) on a set of all possible date and id combinations:

```
import itertools
...
combns = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(df['data'].unique(), df['repair_id'].unique())),
                      columns=['data', 'repair_id'])

new_df = combns.merge(df, on=['data', 'repair_id'], how='left')\
               .fillna(0).sort_values(['data', 'repair_id']).reset_index(drop=True)

#           data repair_id  num_onsite  num_offsite
# 0   2016-02-01         A         3.0          0.0
# 1   2016-02-01         B         2.0          1.0
# 2   2016-02-01         C         0.0          0.0
# 3   2016-02-01         D         0.0          4.0
# 4   2016-02-01         E         0.0          0.0
# 5   2016-02-02         A         1.0          3.0
# 6   2016-02-02         B         0.0          0.0
# 7   2016-02-02         C         1.0          1.0
# 8   2016-02-02         D         0.0          0.0
# 9   2016-02-02         E         0.0          6.0
# 10  2016-02-14         A         1.0          3.0
# 11  2016-02-14         B         0.0          4.0
# 12  2016-02-14         C         0.0          0.0
# 13  2016-02-14         D         2.0          0.0
# 14  2016-02-14         E         3.0          0.0
```